# Flexible gallery solution for Drupal 7

Tags: 7, media

I'm trying to build a site which should have gallery functionality. I think we should be able to solve this with Drupal 7. So my question is: **is there any module/feature etc. (or any combination of modules), which can solve the following?**

- The site is on Drupal 7.
- **(A)** We will have a gallery manager role. Every user with that role should be able to *upload and manage his/her own galleries*. We will have at least 10 person with this role.
- **(B)** A gallery should be able to contain/display/manage ~100 pictures, so *batch uploading and editing (for captions, ordering, etc.)* is necessary.
- Support for usual Drupal goodies like *image styles, Views* etc.
- Support for a *clearbox-like display*, preferably integration with the [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module.
- Support for *YouTube videos* in galleries would be nice, but not a must have.

I've already checked a lot of suggestions in the topic. Alternatives that probably won't work in my case *(please correct me if I'm wrong)*:

- A Drupal 7 version of [Node Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/node_gallery) would solve almost all of this, but it's not likely that we will see anything like that soon. 
  **edit**: Node Gallery is [now completely and totally unsupported](http://drupal.org/node/1557852), meaning that we won't see a D7 port ever.
- [Media Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) is a somewhat incomplete module - I've tried to build the functionality above with that, but I can't see any way to support point **(A)**, not to mention a big bunch of bugs that would make it impossible to use it on a production site. Also it's not maintained well.
- [Field Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) is just a nice formatter, I don't think it's possible to use anything like that in my use case. As far as I can understand, a formatter-based solution won't scale well enough for **(B)**, not to mention the missing management functionality. [Gallery formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) is the same from my point of view.

I would appreciate any suggestions on solving this. I'm not afraid of building something from scratch (whether it means playing around in Views, coding or both), but at least I would like to know where to start to achieve all of this.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use views, a custom post type, feeds importing and lots of coffee?

Comment: @chrisjlee I would be happy to check out your idea if you could explain what should I use to build the (B) part. (See: I should be able to edit information about a bunch of images from the admin interface.)

Comment: You should look into feeds. E.g. you would use a csv to  manage each gallery. That would manage part b. BTW all the suggestions that you provided don't solve part B. They're very messy.

Comment: @chrisjlee Node Gallery would, as I mentioned. Managing each gallery with CSV files - it's should be possible to manage those galleries from admin interface, what about user experience?

Comment: Doing it this way would still allow you to use the drupal user interface, media, or any other module you'd like for the GUI layer of your application. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Over [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/212433), I've posted an initial suggestion for building just what you are asking for, a flexible gallery. If it's of any help to you, you are welcome to take part there. :)

Answer (score 1):

In D7, I do galleries with the image field and the [plup module](http://drupal.org/project/plup). Nothing fancy, but at the same time, probably because it is nothing fancy, you automatically get support for colorbox, permissions (standard core or from contrib like [Field permissions module](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions)), image styles, image captions (using the [image caption module](http://drupal.org/project/image_caption)) and any other (image-)field related functionality.

So far it has fully satisfied my needs